# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters

I am not sure what I'm missing here. I did a few search about this error but I can't not find anything that will on my error. The Home screen page will render all images. Prior to this, when a single image is clicked, it will open a new page to show the image. What i was trying to do is, when the image is clicked, i would like the image PLUS the detailed information of the image. All I get is an empty blank page with the error on dev tools (see below). Thank you in advance...

ProductScreen.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';

function ProductScreen(props) {


  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log("A", id);
  const productId = props.match.params.id; // this is the error as per dev tools
  console.log(props.match.params.id);

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);

  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect = (() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct(productId));
  }, [dispatch, productId]);

 return (

 //code here

  )
}

export default ProductScreen;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdshU.png
```

Comment: What are you passing as props to this component? Have you tried to log `props.match` to see what your `match` object actually contains. It just seems like there is no property `params` on `match`.

Comment: I did console.log and I'm getting undefined.

Comment: And if you log the `props`? You must pass some props to this in the correct structure otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I got an empty object for logging the props.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not passing the props `match` while creating the JSX Element of `ProductScreen`. This line will look like this

```
<ProductScreen match={someMatchObj} />
```

As [@mushroomator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17487348/mushroomator) suggests you should also check if the value is undefined.

Comment: Thank you  @mushroomator for your quick response. This is my JSX for ProductScreen

Comment: I am not [@mushroomator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17487348/mushroomator) :smile:.

Comment: Ohh so I was talking about the code where you (in some sense) invoke ```ProductScreen```

Comment: Sorry @Nikhil Devadiga... ;-)

Comment: Yes, you that is the line that is missing in your question @enuke4. You must call your component `ProductScreen` and pass it the props it needs. If you don't do that they will be `undefined`.

Comment: BTW, the only place I invoked ProductScreen is in my App.js. And this one looks like this. I tried a few things but nothing works so far.

Comment: <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />}></Route>

Comment: This I tried as well <Route path="/product/:id" render={(props) => <ProductScreen {...props} />}></Route>

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of you `App.js` to your question please. You can edit your original question, so no need to post an answer to your own question. Using the edit option will make sure everything necessary to solve your problem can be found in your question.

It seems you are not correctly passing down the props to you `ProductScreen`.  And it seems you are using a frontend routing library. Can you please share which one you are using, as well.

Comment: I guess you are using ```react-router```. Try changing your route as ```<Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen match={someMatchObject}/>}></Route>```

Answer (score 0):

@mushroomator

This is my JSX...

```
 return (

    <div>

      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (

        <div>
          <Link to="/">Back To Result</Link>
          <div className="row top">
            <div className="col-2">
              <img className="large" src={product.image} alt={product.name} ></img>
            </div>

            <div className="col-1">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <Rating
                    rating={product.rating}
                    numReviews={product.numReviews}
                  >
                  </Rating>
                </li>

                <li>
                  Price: ${product.price}
                </li>

                <li>
                  Description:
                  <p>{product.description}</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div className="col-1">
              <div className="card card-body">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <div className="row">
                      <div>Price</div>
                      <div className="price">${product.price}</div>
                    </div>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <div className="row">

                      <div>Status</div>
                      <div>
                        {product.countInStock > 0 ? (
                          <span className="success">In Stock</span>
                        ) : (
                          <span className="danger">Unavailable</span>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <button className="primary block">Add to Cart</button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
 )
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: You should add this to the question itself